# SAS base programming

Tags: join, merge, sas

Is there a way to join/merge two datasets/tables in which one register in dataset B refers at the same time to a row  (condition 1) and  to a column (condition 2) of dataset A?:

Condition 1: b.City = b.getColumnName() AND

Condition 2: b.Part_code  = a.Part_code

What I am looking for would be something equivalent to the getColumnName(), to be able to make the comparison at the same time by row and by column.

Datasets are as follows (simplified examples):

Dataset A:

```
Part_code     Miami    LA

A_1             60000    38000

A_2             5000     2000

A_3             1000     60000
```

Dataset B:

```
Part_code     City

A_1           Miami
```

Desired output (joined):

```
Part_code     City       Part_stock

A_1           Miami      60000
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

What you are really looking to do is pivot the A data set and then filter it based on the cities in the B data set.

Proc Transpose to pivot the table:

```
proc sort data=a;
by part_code;
run;

proc transpose data=A out=A(rename=(_name_=city col1=part_stock));
by part_code;
run;
```

Then use an inner join to filter based on B

```
Proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select a.*
   from A as a
      inner join
        B as b
      on a.part_code = b.part_code
     and a.city = b.city;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

DomPazz's answer is the better solution because the parts table should be restructured to better handle lookups like this.

With that stated, here's a solution that uses the existing table structure. Note that both tables A and B must be sorted by `Part_Code` first.

```
data want;
merge 
    B  (in=b) 
    A  (in=a)
;
by Part_Code;
if a & b;

array invent(*) Miami--LA;

do i = 1 to dim(invent);
    if vname(invent(i)) = City then do;
        stock = invent(i);
        output;
    end;
end;

keep Part_Code City stock;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option, VVALUEX will look up a columns value based on the name.
VVALUEX cannot be used in a SQL query though, if that matters.

```
data tableA;
    infile cards truncover;
    input Part_code  $   Miami LA;
    cards;
A_1             60000    38000
A_2             5000     2000
A_3             1000     60000
;



data tableB;
    infile cards truncover;
    input Part_code $     City $;
    cards;
A_1           Miami
;
run;

proc sort data=tableA;
    by part_code;
run;

proc sort data=tableB;
    by part_code;
run;

data want;
    merge tableB (in=B) tableA (in=A);
    by part_code;

    if B;
    Value=input(vvaluex(City), best32.);
    keep part_code city value;
run;
```